# CC430 circuit isn't working like an almost exact copy

Tags: rf, antenna, debugging

So I have two PCBs(They are Kicksats) with the following schematics:

This is the bad one.
[image: BAD ONE]

This is the good one
[image: GOOD ONE]

The cutoff in the schematic is just the irrelevant solar panels and the block to the right is just an accelerometer which has nothing to do with the radio.
I get the second one that produces a signal like this:
[image]

and the first one to produce a screaming signal like this:
[image]

So I'm sure it's the hardware because I used the same code on both(the results are the above you see). I've tried basically everything to get the bad one to work. I've changed gauges of wires for the antennae, tried changing the lengths to the half wave length and quarter wavelength(I'm working with 868 MHz). I've repopulated the board. I've made another one entirely again. I put on an LED just to make sure that I put on the microcontroller the right way and no luck.
 Here is what each looks like: The Good one:
[image]

The Bad one:
[image]

Any suggestions are welcome.

This is the schematic for the bad
[image]

This is the schematic for the good not including the solar panels(which I've detached.)
[image]

Comment: What DFT diagnostics were designed into it for self-test? And if not , why?

Comment: Am I interpreting your 'bad' board correctly when I see C5, C6, L1 somewhere over near JP5 - whereas these parts are right up next to the micro on the 'good' board? Whereabout is C3 (the 470nF connected to pin 7 on the micro) located?

Comment: @brhans Yes you are right. The C5,C6,L1 are located near JP5 on the bad versus right near the MCU on the good. C3 is located by itself on the top left of the schematic on the bad(see above) and the analogue on the good board is right next to the MCU. I've added the schematics above.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I put an LED on there to know that I put the MCU in the right configuration. I didn't put many other checks... It was a mistake in designing it. But the MCU is responsive. I can talk to it and flash it and all the passives I checked by hand and it seems they are working properly.

Comment: Also, last I checked I was getting the 26 MHz clock output from the crystal so that works as well.

Comment: Do you have a solid ground plane around and under the antenna part? The good one seems to have a keepout under most of the antenna stuff.

Comment: @Arsenal ...Yes... I have a solid ground plane on one side and a solid 3.3V plane on the other. Do you think that's the reason why?

Comment: Those last are the layouts rather than schematics (which you posted earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it's because I'm getting reflections off the connection between the antennas and the board. The signal gets muddled to death there. I think that's why I'm not getting a signal... I may be wrong. I'll edit this when I get the new boards with the impedance matched RF transmission lines.

Comment: I hope you also moved all the decoupling caps a *lot* closer to the micro too. I'd bet $10 that TI's app-notes for that part tell you to put them right up next to it.

Comment: Yes I did that too. ;) How do I give you a thumbs up? Haha